# How do you use ActiveRecord3's associations feature outside of Rails?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I am working on a script to translate an old Rails 2 application database into a new Rails 3 application.  The new application is a rewrite and simplification of the database schema.

I have created a stand-alone ruby program independent of Rails to do the heavy lifting and am leveraging the adapter pattern with Ruby modules to manipulate two database connections and move the data from one system to the other.

I have successfully implemented ActiveRecord (using include "active_record") in my translator models and all my find and validations are working as expected.  However, the associations are resulting in method_missing calls.

Do I need to do something special to allow the associations to work outside of the Rails environment?  I'm hoping for a simple answer like "you forgot to require this key file".

Comment: Can you post some code samples?  Your line about 'include "active_record"' sounds like it might be a problem.  To make AR work correctly, your model classes need to inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`, eg: `class Something < ActiveRecord::Base`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a minimal example using activerecord without rails:

```
require 'active_record'

class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :site
end



ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter => 'mysql',
  :database => 'test',
  :user => 'root'
)

s = Site.first

p s
p s.users
p s.users[0].site
```

There is really no more than this !
The gem used here is activerecord 3 but the exact same example works with activerecord 2.

PS: obviously you need a test database with a sites and users tables to run this test.